# What is the difference between circular and rotational motion?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, definition, rotational-kinematics

I am asking what is the difference between circular and rotational motion. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is rather vague I will try to comment on it.

Circular motion is literally the motion of an object on a circle, subject to the centripetal force. For example when you swing around a ball at the end of a rope. For problems involving circular motion it is often enough to just know the velocity and mass of the object.

Rotational motion is the motion whereby an object rotates around a given axis. For example when you take ball and spin it around. Contrary to the case of circular motion it is (in general) necessary to know the moment of inertia when solving problems involving rotational motion.

So in a sense one could consider circular motion as a special kind of rotational motion where the axis around which you rotate lies outside of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia answers this well ([Rotation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation)).

> **A rotation is a circular movement of an object around a center (or point) of rotation.** A three-dimensional object can always be rotated around an infinite number of imaginary lines called rotation axes (/ˈæksiːz/ AK-seez). If the axis passes through the body's center of mass, the body is said to rotate upon itself, or spin. A rotation about an external point, e.g. the Earth about the Sun, is called a revolution or orbital revolution, typically when it is produced by gravity. The axis is called a pole.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>